# Xcode 9: Block-compressed payload operation failed

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode9-beta

MacBook Pro El Capitan (10.11.6) here. I'm trying to install Xcode 9 so that I can play around with [ARKit](https://developer.apple.com/arkit/). From the Apple Developer's site, the only version of 9 I can find is `Xcode_9_beta_6.xip` (please correct me if I'm wrong!), so I download it:

[image]

Then I extract & run the XIP file:

[image]

But that operation fails due to this strange error that Google doesn't really help me out with (at all):

> The operation couldn't be completed. Block-compressed payload operation failed

[image]

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: You probably need to update your os to sierra mac os.

Comment: @Apple: Please add requirements/version checking to your Xcode installation process and provide a meaningful error message if these checks fail. Sincerely, smeeb from SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use at least the version 10.12.6 to install Xcode 9 beta 6 , I had the same problem but this solved after update my MacOs version, you can try unzip the file with Archive Utility.

Comment: I just downloaded High Sierra today, there is no way to be more updated, and it still fails to open the .xip file

Comment: You don't need to download a xip to get XCode 9 anymore... Why don't use appstore?

Comment: Because it also downloaded corrupted from the App Store

Comment: I think that is other problem... likely, it would worth ask with more details in other post to help you :D

Comment: App Store worked on the fifth attempt a day later 

Answer (score 4):

`xip -x Xcode_12.5_beta_2.xip` worked for me today.

Comment: This worked for me today after trying to open xcode 13.4.1 with the GUI XIP on OSX Ventura.